# Searching an Excel workbook and listing results in another sheet or report using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, search

I'm trying to build a search function to search the current workbook. The idea is to have it be almost like a query so when I search for whatever, it lists the results on the search outcome page or creates a report of the search results. I don't know a damn thing about VBA. So far I only have a code that allows me to do so on the same page as the data. The odd part is it can pull the searchwords from another tab but I just can't figure out a good scheme to search all pages and list results in my Search tab.

```
Sub finddata()

Dim studentname As String
Dim finalrow As Integer 
Dim i As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet

Sheets("Search").Range("H1:Z15").ClearContents

studentname = Sheets("Home").TextBox1.Text
finalrow = Sheets("Search").Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row




    For i = 1 To finalrow
        If Cells(i, 1) = studentname Then
            Sheets("Search").Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 6)).Copy
            Sheets("Search").Range("H20").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            End If
    Next i

 End Sub
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what is your question please?

Comment: FYI, you need to fully qualify the `Cells()` with the sheet expected to run it on, i.e. `Sheets("Search").Cells(i,1),Sheets("Search").Cells(i,6)).Copy`, otherwise it may throw an error, or return unexpected results.  What have you tried, for looping through the worksheets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the best search scheme depends a lot on the structure of your data and the ways it can change over time, the following should work for what you've described.

```
Sub findata()

Dim studentname As String
Dim finalrow As Integer
Dim i As Integer, n As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet, Srch As Worksheet, hm As Worksheet
Dim wkbk As Workbook

Set wkbk = ThisWorkbook
Set Srch = wkbk.Sheets("Search")
Set hm = wkbk.Sheets("Home")

Srch.Range("H1:Z15").ClearContents
studentname = hm.Cells(2, 3).Value

For n = 3 To wkbk.Sheets.Count
    Set sh = wkbk.Sheets(n)
    finalrow = sh.Range("A10000").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To finalrow
        If sh.Cells(i, 1) = studentname Then
            With sh
                .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, 6)).Copy
            End With
            Srch.Range("H20").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
        End If
    Next i
Next n
```

A few things to notice:

1) I'm assuming your data are stored on sheets other than "Search" and "Home".  The code above assumes they will be sheets 1 & 2, and that all following sheets are to be searched.

2) I'm not aware of a way to grab the value of a text box directly, though there may be a way.  I've found the best way is to set the "LinkedCell" property to a specific cell that is hidden from your user's view.  In the above code, that cell would be C2 [or hm.Cells(2,3)].

3) You had previously specified "xLPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats".  Make sure you really want that.  If your formulas are relational, they will not survive being copied to your results list.

Good luck!  If this helps, please mark it as an answer and vote it up.  I'm just getting started here too!

,Mike Shanahan

Comment: Thanks, this is great! I do have two more questions about this code if you care to answer. 

1. How do I make this work from another sheet. If I have the macro on the Home page then the macro runs and clears previous results on the Search page but does not put the new info in. (if run from the search page it works perfectly)

2. How do I make it so when a user presses the macro on the Home page, it will change the display to the Search page so they can see the results.

Comment: Let's hit the 2nd question 1st.  Add the statement "Srch.Activate" just before your "End Sub" line to move the user to the results sheet.
I cannot reproduce the problem you describe in your 1st question.  Generally, you should always write your commands such that the Worksheet you want to work in/on is explicitly called.  In the line that pastes the results, the "Srch" has been defined as the Search worksheet, so that statement should work no matter what the active sheet is.  Are you certain that the query which yields results when run from search, yields nothing when run from home?

Comment: You were correct on both! thanks! i'm too new to give your answer an upvote, but you've more than earned the answer check! Thanks!